# З чого складається вибірка з сигналу? З проб, зразків, ...?

Tags: from-english, вибір-слова

Припустимо, що ми опитуємо якійсь пристрій з певною частотою. Як назвати один *sample*? Тобто якщо ми опитали цей пристрій *N* разів, то маємо набір [*f<sub>0</sub>, ..., f<sub>N-1</sub>*]. Як назвати *f<sub>i</sub>*?

Я знайшов різні варіанти: вибірка, зразок, проба, взяток, навіть [відлік](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B2_%D0%92%D1%96%D1%82%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%A8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0) є. Чи існує усталений варіант для такого контексту?

Answer (score 3):

Наскільки я розумію, проблема полягає у перекладі слова <sub>англ.</sub>*sample*.

Особисто мені подобається варіант ***куштунок***.

---

Google Translate пропонує наступні варіанти (у порядку, запропонованого  джерелом):

- *вибірка* — sample
  Тут мається на увазі, що слово *вибірка* може означати як *групу of samples*, так і один екземпляр (specimen).
- *зразок* — sample, template, specimen, example, model, pattern
  Мені цей варіант здається нудним
- *приклад* — example, instance, sample, lead, illustration, paradigm
  Це слово має багато інших застосувань, тому його використовувати тут, напевне, не варто.
- *шаблон* — template, pattern, mold, stencil, sample, jig
  Неточно, у даному контексті.
- ***куштунок*** — trial, proof, experiment, sample
  Чудовий варіант. Словник української мови за ред. Б. Грінченка (1907—1909) [подає наступне тлумачення](http://wiki.kubg.edu.ua/%D0%9A%D1%83%D1%88%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA):

  > **Куштунок, -нку,** м. Проба; отвѣдываніе.
  >   *Оце сотня яблук на продаж, а одно дай на куштунок людім.* Харьк¹.
- *проба* — sample, test, trial, analysis, proof, alloy
  Це більше схоже на явище, не підходить
- *модло* — model, sample, pattern
  Щось незвичне і, напевне, не підходить.

---

¹ — *Харьк., Харьк. у., Харьк. г.* — Харьковскій уѣздъ, Харьковская

Comment: Мені більш до душі **проба**.  *Ми зібрали дані для аналізу. Маємо 20 проб (сигналу). 7 і 12 проба дуже виділяються від решти.*

Comment: Мені здається, що *куштунок* все ж походить від [*куштувати*](http://sum.in.ua/s/kushtuvaty). Дотично це підтверджує й цитована вами стаття зі словника Грінченка: *отвѣдываніе*, від рос. *отведать*, що відповідає українському *куштувати*. Тому в даному контексті не найвдаліший варіант, на мою думку. Підтримую, як і @finesoul, варіант *проба*.

Comment: можна ще додати варіант *елементарна подія*, бо [простір елементарних подій](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%96%D1%80_%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%96%D0%B9)